# How to align tilemap, grid and sprites to center? (Unity 2D Tilemap)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game similar to Rimworld and I have issues aligning the tilemap, grid and sprites so that they all work as intended functionally and visually.

The default offset for the `tile anchor` is `0.5, 0.5, 0` and this works entirely until I drop a sprite in the center of the tile, where it appears to be positioned bottom-left (with the sprite's pivot set to `Center`).

[image]

This is a problem because I'd have to manually set an offset (0.5, 0.5, 0) for every single object I instantiate to match the visuals of the tilemap. I tried setting the `tile anchor` to 0 but then the tilemap moves while the grid position stays the same which messes up click detection. (if only I could move the grid back by (-0.5, -0.5, 0)?

[image]

Is there an elegant and easy solution for all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a perfect custom alignment for a tilemap or sprite the easiest solution is to take a empty gameobject as spawner , take the position of that empty spawner object and and then instantiate those tile or other prefab at the exact location where you kept those spawner objects by your choice.

Answer (score 1):

something a friend of mine told me, is that instead of trying to align it to the grid so it always moves in the center, just hold ctrl while using the move tool on the sprite that you are moving. It can get annoying, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

basicly if you change the sprite pivot for top-left or something different of center should work, for me works perfectly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my 2d game. when I want to put the tiles, they place with some offset.

You can change the pivot value in the sprite editor for any sprite ( tiles, character, ...) to a custom pivot like (0,0,0), I suggest center value for the pivot.

[image: Sprite editor]

You can change Tile Ancher for any Tilemap objects too.

[image: Tilemap]

this helps you to put anything to map how you are comfortable.

[image: Result]